# How to write to stdout within a conditional expression in MIT-Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, mit-scheme

Here is an example of an attempt to write a different string to stdout depending on the value of a variable:

```
(let ((x 1))
(cond ((< x 2)  
         (display "hooray"))
       (else 
         (display "bummer"))) 
)
```

Notice that the correct string does get written, but we also get an "Unspecified return value"

My understanding is that this happens because the interpreter is trying to return the value of the "consequent expression" of the clause as the value of the conditional, but the "display" expression does not return any value.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Keep in mind that the return value is only printed in the REPL, if you run this from the command line `mit-scheme --quiet --load ./my-file` return values are not printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this expression is evaluated only for its effect (printing a message), you should explicitly return a value (any value!) as the result of the `let` form:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (cond ((< x 2)  
         (display "hooray")
         (newline))
        (else 
         (display "bummer")
         (newline)))
  'ok)
```

Now we'll get:

```
hooray
'ok
```